# How to print emojis in C?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, emoji

How to print emojis in C programming language?
Like (, , , ....)etc.

I wrote this code but it does not work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("\U0001F600");
    return 0;
}
```

But this code gives me an output as

```
≡ƒÿÇ
```

And the correct emoji is

Comment: Use a text viewer that support emoji to view the output.

Comment: Ok @MikeCAT can you elaborate it

Comment: Your code worked perfectly for me.  But, I know that the environment where I compile and run C programs is configured to display UTF-8 output.  It sounds like maybe yours is not.  What OS are you using?  What C compiler are you using?  How are you running your program?  (Typing its name in a command window?  Clicking a Run button in an IDE?)

Comment: For example, you can run your code and see your emoji on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bgJnScmG0tQF7zzU).

Comment: Ok great @SteveSummit but I am running it on VS Code

Comment: I added the visual-studio-code tag.  Perhaps someone who's familiar with that platform will be able to help.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/docs/editor/tasks.md#changing-the-encoding-for-a-task-output

Comment: Oh yeah, @MikeCAT, it is also  running good in programiz also

Comment: Of course. The problem is not in the program, the problem you have is how the console window you use to see the output handles that output. Some default to utf8. VSCode's does not (unless your windows environment is configured for utf8)

Comment: (note: when using `chcp` as the link above suggests, the value for UTF8 is 65001)

Comment: ok @spectras my encoding is in utf8.

Comment: So, what should I do all my settings are in utf8, but still output is not showing.

Comment: compiler gcc 8.1.0